# Foreigner with a California state ID. Do I need my passport for US domestic flights?

Tags: usa, air-travel, passports, paperwork

I am a foreigner studying in California under an F-1 visa. I will be traveling by plane to Chicago, DC and New York and I was wondering if my California ID Card would be enough, or if I should also carry my passport and I-20?

Comment: Very, very rarely, the US Customs and Border Protection have checked ID's of passengers on domestic flights. See [Federal agents ask domestic flight passengers to show IDs in search for immigrant ordered deported](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/post-nation/wp/2017/02/23/federal-agents-ask-domestic-flight-passengers-to-show-ids-in-search-for-undocumented-immigrant/?utm_term=.fda9c1579d05). Even then, ID should be sufficient.

Answer (score 6):

You do **not** have to carry your passport or I20. Your Californian ID is enough.

Source: [TSA website](https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/identification)

Comment: thanks! I saw something similar online but the guidelines of several universities advise to always carry passport + I-20...

Comment: @Oli if you run into border patrol, you might need those.  Border patrol operates in airports on the Mexican border, like McAllen, TX.  For your destinations, you don't need to worry about it.  But if you're the worrying type, by all means take the documents if it will allow you to worry less.

Comment: @Oli When entering the Country yes. Not even the border patrol will expect you to carry a thick booklet and a couple of A4 Sheets in your everyday life. With your state ID, they can look you up in the I-94 and SEVIS records if needed

Comment: The part of the law that causes anal retentive lawyers to recommend that you carry documentation is [INA 264(e)](https://www.uscis.gov/ilink/docView/SLB/HTML/SLB/0-0-0-1/0-0-0-29/0-0-0-8289.html). Hardly any green card holders pay attention to this, however, and with the demise of paper I-94 cards it is hard for non-immigrants to even know what it is they are supposed to carry. Non-enforcement has kind of rendered this moot, though it is still technically the law.

Comment: @Dennis Based on the wording, it would appear it only applies to permanent residents. The Alien Registration act of 1940 concerns permanent residents

Comment: @Crazydre, I'm pretty sure that's not right. The Alien Registration Act was passed at a time when US law did not yet strongly distinguish between resident and non-resident aliens. I believe it applies to all aliens, there weren't separate classes then.

Comment: @Crazydre, P.S. I'm pretty sure the address they demand of visitors when entering the US is to satisfy that law as well.

Comment: @Dennis "the address they demand of visitors when entering the US is to satisfy that law as well" Why, then, do they not require it for resident Aliens?

Comment: @Crazydre, they do. They are actually quite strict that LPRs update their address with USCIS when they move, I think you have to do it within 10 days.

Comment: @Dennis Yes you're right, remembered now that the blue customs form (although now largely obsolete for Americans and visa-free People) requires an address. Confused it with APIS, whereby legal residents and US citizens don't Need to fill in the address of the first night's stay

Comment: w/ regards to border patrol, you probably wouldn't be issued a proper state ID if you are not a documented immigrant, unless in some states they issue it to people qualified for DACA. But if that's the case you shouldn't worry anyway. So basically you're right the ID per se is almost always enough.